# Where can I find a complete list of Game Room games?

Tags: xbox-360

Where can I find the complete list of available Xbox 360 *Game Room* games?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Game_Room_games

It also stated which Pack they are in so you know which one to download.